# mongoimport: Uncaught: SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input (Valid JSON, jsonArray, size 2.8MB)

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose

It is not possible to import data from the JSON file to the database when protecting the container via Docker-Compose, there is an error “Uncaught: Syntaxerror: Unexpected End of Json Input”. Please offer options to solve the problem

In the terminal, this command is executed

```
mongoimport --db=pdd --collection=tickets --type=json --file /.docker/tickets.json --jsonArray
```

init-mongo.js

```
const fs = require('fs');
const { spawn } = require('child_process');

const importTickets = async () => {
  try {
    const path = '/.docker/tickets.json';

    if (!fs.existsSync(path)) {
      throw new Error(`Файл ${path} не найден.`);
    }

    const mongoimport = spawn('mongoimport', ['--db=pdd', '--collection=tickets', '--type=json', '--jsonArray']);

    const inputStream = fs.createReadStream(path);
    inputStream.pipe(mongoimport.stdin);

    const stdoutChunks = [];
    const stderrChunks = [];

    mongoimport.stdout.on('data', (data) => stdoutChunks.push(data));
    mongoimport.stderr.on('data', (data) => stderrChunks.push(data));

    await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      mongoimport.on('close', (code) => {
        if (code === 0) {
          const nInserted = JSON.parse(Buffer.concat(stdoutChunks).toString()).nInserted;
          console.log(`${nInserted} документов было импортировано в коллекцию tickets.`);
          resolve();
        } else {
          const errorMsg = Buffer.concat(stderrChunks).toString();
          console.error(`Произошла ошибка при импорте данных в коллекцию tickets. ${errorMsg}`);
          reject(new Error(errorMsg));
        }
      });
    });
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err.message);
  }
};

importTickets();
```

Comment: Try a small JSON file first. The error indicates something about the JSON data or file being imported.

Comment: Try using the [tool](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) `jq` on the file and see if it can parse the data.